# loop freezing and memory consumption

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code and I want to implement this on my app. But I am thinking that this code is freezing my browser? What is the best and right way to implement this loop so I can get an updated data on my browser without using a lot of memory?

```js
$scope.mydata = {};

function GetData(){
         $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/Payroll-tracking-system/json/rex.json',
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            $scope.mydata = response.data;
            GetData();
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });

    }
    
 GetData();
 console.log($scope.mydata);
```

Comment: That code will run in an infinite loop until it hits an error. Is this what you want to happen?

Comment: You should throttle the calls with something like `setTimeout`

Comment: @rorymorris89 I want to enhance the code.. It seems the code is consuming a lot of memory? and it's freezing the browser..

Comment: @RexAdrivan Why are you calling GetData() inside function GetData ? It will definitely become an infinite loop

Comment: Infinite loops will do that, what do you want to achieve? Do you want this to run over and over again?

Comment: @rorymorris89 should I put timeout or possibly break the first loop so it will free the memory?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do! Do you need to make the http request multiple times?

Comment: @SahanSerasinghe Im using loops to update the data..

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. See the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800).

Comment: @EmileBergeron Hello, I'm currently trying the webworker.. the infinite loop is not recommended and will freeze your browser...

Comment: I mean, tell us why you want an infinite loop, then we'll be able to help.

Comment: @EmileBergeron looping through HTTP.GET to get the latest data to the browser...

Comment: How often does it change? Could it wait a couple seconds between calls? Even minutes? Please edit your question with the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

## Web Worker

I would suggest moving this effectively infinite loop into a [Web Worker](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) which can post messages back to the main thread whenever they're useful.

A couple of other useful resources for learning about them are:

- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

The major benefit of using workers, is that the code runs asynchronously and effectively in a parallel thread, freeing up the main thread for general user interaction.

### As requested (kind of)

In your main script:

```
// create the blob from a string of JS code
var blob = new Blob( [ '(function(){"use strict";' +
    '...self.addEventListener("message", function(evt){...}, false);' +
    '...self.postMessage( msg );...}());' ] ),
    // get a URL for the worker
    blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL( blob ),
    // create the worker from the URL
    wrkr = new Worker( blobURL );
// prepare to listen to the worker's messages
wrkr.addEventListener( "message", function( evt ) {
    // use evt.data passed to script from worker
}, false );
// start the worker with
wrkr.postMessage( /* any information the worker needs */ );
```

The specifics of how the worker needs to be written, what messages it sends, and how to handle those messages will depend on the rest of the application's code and function.

The worker will not have access to any of the functions, variables, constants *etc.* in the main script unless they're handed to it on initialization, so the code will need to be able to stand alone.

A standard [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) format will work just fine by the looks of things.

Use the [`wrkr.terminate()` or `self.close()` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Terminating_a_worker) to kill it when you need to.

Comment: Web Workers run in an isolated thread. As a result, the code that they execute needs to be contained in a separate file. I dont need to run it on a seperate file..

Comment: Workers can be created from strings that do not require an extra file. See [the html5rocks article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers) for details.

Comment: sorry to bug bro.. do you have a JSfiddle conversion of the script to webworker?

Comment: Added some more details, but as noted, there are too many unknowns to provide a copy/paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are trying to call the `GetData` function in the function itself. If you want to process the data returned by that function, you should call that function with a different name.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sahansera/bkUEu/4812/) for you to simulate your problem

First, open the console of your browser and click on Run on the JSFiddle UI. Observe that it outputs the result (an empty object in our case).

Then uncomment the following line (Line no. 15) as I have instructed in the code.

```
// Uncomment the following line and see that it runs to an infinite loop
// GetData();
```

You will see that it will run continuously.

Hope it helps to understand the root cause of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Can u show the data that you are getting from the API call. You must have pagination enabled, if you are not sending the data in a single API call, also you are updating the same variable, how will you use the data if the data keeps changing.
You should probably add the data that is coming from the api to $scope.data.

If you are sending pagination, then you should only call GetData() when there are more results available.

An example would be:

```
$scope.mydata = []; //if the data is array, modify it according to your use
var start = 0;
var limit = 20;
function GetData(){
     $http({
        method: 'GET',
        params:{
          start:start,
          limit:limit
        }
        url: 'http://localhost/Payroll-tracking-system/json/rex.json',
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // add the data
        $scope.mydata = $scope.mydata.concat(response.data);
        start = start + limit;
        //response.total from the api
        if(start > response.total) return; 
        else GetData();
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```